# How to prevent child element executing onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got the following markup on the page

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="box_child_one"></div>
    <div id="box_child_two"></div>
    <div id="box_child_three"></div>
</div>
```

I need to trigger the **onmousedown** event on all elements inside the **#box** div so i've got this javascript code:

```
var element = "#box";
document.querySelector(element).onmousedown = function() {
    alert("triggered");
};
```

However, I do not want onmousedown being triggered on the **#box_child_three** element.
How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `event.target` to find out which element was actually clicked on.

```js
var element = "#box";
document.querySelector(element).onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== "box_child_three") {
        alert("triggered");
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div id="box_child_one">one</div>
    <div id="box_child_two">two</div>
    <div id="box_child_three">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `stopPropagation` for the event when element three is clicked so that it doesn't bubble up to the parent (`box`) element.

```js
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', () => 
  alert('triggered')
);

document.getElementById('box_child_three').addEventListener('click', e => 
  e.stopPropagation()
);
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="box_child_one">one</div>
  <div id="box_child_two">two</div>
  <div id="box_child_three">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="box_child_one" trigger></div>
    <div id="box_child_two" trigger></div>
    <div id="box_child_three"></div>
</div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#box').onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target.hasAttribute('trigger')){
    alert('event fired')
  }
}
</script>
```

I'd go for this. As you are now no longer relying on an id to carry this out making it more re-usable